# How to list out the latest created files in CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

In Windows command prompt, how do I list out the latest created files in a system drive (e.g. C:)?

I would like to test a software that creates unknown temporary files in various places within the system drive, and like to know when each files is created during runtime, and want to make sure that the uninstallation does indeed remove these files.

My idea is to start the program, and repeatedly search in command prompt. Or is there a simpler way to track?

Comment: You want to test an application which creates unknown temporary files not being really temporary anywhere on system drive? This sounds like a malware application.

Comment: I suggest to run before starting the application `dir %SystemDrive%\ /A-D /N /ON /S /TC >C:\Temp\FilesListBefore.txt` and run finally the same command with redirecting output to file `C:\Temp\FilesListAfter.txt` whereby the directory `C:\Temp` must of course already exist. Then you can compare the two list files and find out which files have been added. You could use the option `/B` instead of `/N` and don't specify `/TC` to get just the file names with full path into the list files. Run in a command prompt window `dir /?` for more details.

Comment: @Mofi, you're right. I am suspecting the software has malware in it. I tried to check with ollydbg but there is too much to read throughout the entire runtime, so I thought tracking files creation as an option. Unfortunately, C:/Temp would be too obvious to be the only directories, so I want to search the entire system C: drive.

Comment: @KMC Use [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx): Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity.

Comment: @Mofi, why removing switch `/TC` from `dir` when using `/B`?

Comment: @DavidPostill, are you sure procmon still works on win8.1? I simply created a text file manually and it is not even shown on File System Activity...

Comment: @KMC The command line with __DIR__ outputs a list of ALL files on system drive redirected to `FilesListBefore.txt` and `FilesListAfter.txt` in directory `C:\Temp`.

Comment: @aschipfl `/TC` is simply useless when using bare output format specified with `/B` as no time information is output. In other words with using `/B` the usage of option `/T` is superfluous because having no effect on output.

Comment: @Mofi, there is no more time info in the output with `/B`, BUT the sort order is still affected by `/T`...

Comment: @aschipfl `dir %SystemDrive%\ /A-D /B /ON /S` and `dir %SystemDrive%\ /A-D /B /ON /S /TC` produce the same output list in my test on Windows 7 x64. The order of the file names is defined with `/ON` and therefore time specification should not matter. But for NTFS drives, as Windows system drives usually are, the parameter `/ON` is not really needed and `dir %SystemDrive%\ /A-D /B /S` without or with `/TC` or `/TW` or `/TA` produce identical list files. For FAT drives `/ON` is required to get the list files sorted and not listed as currently stored in file allocation table.

Comment: @Mofi, I am aware of all that, but I did not realise that you are using the `/ON` option, sorry for that; instead I was fixated upon a sort order by age (which would have made sense in the situation at hand as the OP was talking about the "latest created files"); so, of course, the sort order is not affected by `/TC` when `/ON` is used...